# Долго работает следующий алгоритм

Tags: php

Страница грузится 30 секунд, затем вылетает:

> `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ...\www\tests.php on line 14`

При этом часть страницы загружает.

```
$count  = 0;
$arr[0] = 0;
While ($count < 20) {
    $count2 = 0;
    $a      = false;
    while (!$a) {
        $num = rand(1, mysql_num_rows($myrow) - 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($num != $arr[$i])
                $count2++;

        }
        if ($count2 == count($arr)) {
            $arr[$count] = $num;
            $a           = true;
        }
    }
    $count++;
    printf("%s<br><br>а)%s<br>б)%s<br>в)%s<br>", mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'question'), mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var1'), mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var2'), mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var3'));

    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var4') != null) {
        echo 'г) ' . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var4') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var5') != null) {
        echo 'д) ' . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var5') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var6') != null) {
        echo 'е) ' . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var6') . '<br>';
    }
    if (mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var7') != null) {
        echo 'ж) ' . mysql_result($myrow, $num, 'var7') . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Хочу сделать проверку, чтобы вопросы которые уже были, не повторялись.

Comment: Не правильно работаете с циклами.

Comment: жуть жуткая... правильно ли я понял, что в базе есть одинаковые вопросы и вы хотите вывести только не повторяющиеся? либо по какому принципу ворос считается уникальным?

Comment: Первое что бросилось в глаза - это вы просто так тираните мускуль...
например 2 раза вызываете mysql_result($myrow,$num,'var4')
Не проще ли сделать так:
$xx = mysql_result($myrow,$num,'var4');
 if ($xx!=null) {echo 'г) '.$xx.'<br>';}

Не говоря уже обо всем остальном.
Дайте полный код, вместе с запросом, а то непонятно что именно вы хотите, уверен сделать это можно просто правильным запросом, возможно достаточно одного  DISTINCT в запросе

Comment: зацикливается цикл отсюда повисание кода... Думается, мне так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень выдает себя вот этот **участок кода**:

```
$a = false;
    while (!$a) {
        $num = rand(1, mysql_num_rows($myrow) - 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
            if ($num != $arr[$i])
                $count2++;
        }
```

В цикле `while` переменная `$a` нигде не модифицируется! Значит цикл впадает в бесконечность, так как `!$a - это False`. Попробуйте изменить код.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ...\www\tests.php on line 14
```

Даю пари, что 14-ая строка - это одна из строк цикла =)

Comment: Пари держат, а не дают))

И посчитайте фигурные скобки в вашем куске - вы не весь цикл скопировали)

Answer (score 1):

при использовании конструкции while() необходимо всегда предусматривать выход из цикла, иначе как у вас при малейшей оплошности будет бесконечный цикл. по поводу вопросы которые уже показывались, судя по вашему коду они просто выбираются случайным образом, для этого переделываем запрос в базу следующим образом:

```
   $result = mysql_query("select * from table order by rand() limit 20");
   //формируем массив для вариантов ответов.
   $variants=array(1=>"а","б","в","г","д","е","ж");
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['question'],'<br>';
    foreach($variants as $k=>$r){
     if($row['var'.$k])echo $r,') ',$row['var'.$k],'<br>';
    }
   }
```

Comment: если в таблице очень много строк, то `ORDER BY RAND()` лучше избежать. Буквально вчера в соседнем вопросе это вспоминали.

Comment: @ikoolik странно что вас только order by rand() смутило, так же не желательно пользоваться mysql_* функциями, и структура БД тоже далека от совершенства, я всегда стараюсь отвечать на уровне задающего вопрос, иначе получится слишком много кода, включая обработчики ошибок, обертки, защиты и т.д. думаю самое главное ухватить суть, а как правильно ею распрорядиться, дело каждого. p.s. сомневаюсь, что в базе будет много записей.